# Laravel 9: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I'm working with Laravel 9 and I have used this column at `users` table for storing user mobile phone number:

```
$table->integer('usr_mobile_phone');
```

And at the factor, I tried this to fill out this column:

```
public function definition()
    {
        $fs = '091';
        $ch = '1234567890';
        $str = $fs.str_shuffle($ch);

        return [
            'usr_mobile_phone' => $str
            ...
        ];
    }
```

But when I run **`php artisan db:seed`**, I get this error:

### **SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'usr_mobile_phone' at row 1**

So what's going wrong here?

How can I store the number properly at the user's mobile phone number column in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `integer` has a maximum range of `2147483647` and minimum      `-2147483648` if it is signed (- / +) and maximum of `4294967295` and minimum of `0` when it is not. So inserting a phone number that usually has a 11 digits exceed its maximum value and depends on how your number is formatted like [@Amjad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7025223/amjad) said you cannot put a string in an integer column so using a `varchar` or `$table->string()` in laravel is a good idea.

[Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `varchar` type for phone numbers, as if i will use `+` character it will not be valid in integer, and it will remove the `0` in the beginning if it was integer, so make it `varchar`